# Connection to the layout renderer failed, Java error?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I´m trying to code a small app for a college course but I get this error when I open de designer

Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java.JavaErrorMessageException: The operation Initialize failed due to an internal error: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java.JavaProcessConnection.d__57.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java\JavaProcessConnection.cs:line 273
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java.JavaProcessConnection.d__52.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java\JavaProcessConnection.cs:line 207
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java.JavaProcessConnection.d__50.MoveNext() in E:\A_work\12\s\Xamarin.Designer.Android\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner\Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.Java\JavaProcessConnection.cs:line 167

Comment: Report an issue using the `Help` menu of Visual Studio.

Comment: Is Visual Studio configured with Android development environment?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes it was. I ended up creating a new solution and wrote the same code.